# Ruby Based Blogging Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack

What Rack enabled blogging engines exist? I want to deploy a free blog to heroku and need more customizabilty than the free hosting of Wordpress.com or Blogerty provide.

Also in another note, has anyone tried to port Wordpress to Ruby?

Answer (score 12):

In any special order:

== Rack based

- [toto](https://github.com/cloudhead/toto)
- [ruby-slippers](https://github.com/dreamr/ruby-slippers)  based on toto

== Jekyll based

- [Jekyll itself](http://jekyllrb.com/)
- [Octopress](https://github.com/imathis/octopress) blogging in jekyll
- [spinto](https://github.com/mixonic/spinto) jekyll cms
- [prose](https://github.com/prose/prose) jekyll cms

== Rails based

- [typo](https://github.com/fdv/typo) one of the oldest in active, with more features but more complex
- [enki](https://github.com/xaviershay/enki) for hackers, basic code
- [simplelog](https://github.com/rbazinet/simplelog) just main features
- [mephisto](https://github.com/halorgium/mephisto) not developed anymore
- [radiant](https://github.com/radiant/radiant) generic CMS

== Rails engines

- [refinerycms](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms) generic CMS
- [refinerycms-blog](https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms-blog) blog engine that integrates with refinerycms
- [blogit](https://github.com/KatanaCode/blogit)
- [ComfortableMexicanSofa](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa) generic CMS
- [comfy-blog](https://github.com/comfy/comfy-blog) blog engine that integrates with ComfortableMexicanSofa
- [Monologue](https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue): minimalistic blog engine with very few dependencies.
- [squeaky](https://github.com/soffes/)
- [hitchens](https://github.com/iancanderson/hitchens)
- [kublog](https://github.com/innku/)
- [jabe](https://github.com/pixels-and-bits/jabe)
- [locomotivecms](http://www.locomotivecms.com/) generic cms
- [BrowserCMS](https://github.com/browsermedia/browsercms) generic CMS

== Integrate jekyll with Rails

- [bloggy](https://github.com/zbruhnke/bloggy)

Answer (score 3):

If you're a fan of git, you might try [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/). It is a static site generator which allows you to do some templating. You don't need a database which makes running it on Heroku even easier.

Answer (score 2):

It's been awhile since I looked into this, but I believe the two major Ruby blog applications are still [Mephisto](http://mephistoblog.com/) and [Typo](http://wiki.github.com/fdv/typo/). They've both been around awhile and appear to still be maintained.

As Heroku has a read-only file system, you may need to do some tweaking to get them to work. Here's a [blog post](http://pagalan.com/2009/09/18/hurdles-of-typo-5-3-in-heroku) on getting Typo running on Heroku.

You may also want to take a look at [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org), which is more of a traditional CMS system, but can be used for blogging. There's actually a [tutorial on the Heroku blog](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/26/radiant_cms_in_5_minutes_or_less/) about getting it up and running on their platform.

Finally, if you want something a bit more lightweight but with full CSS control you may want to take a look at [Scanty](http://github.com/adamwiggins/scanty). It might require you go get your hands dirty, but seems to run great on Heroku. In fact, it's written by one of the founders.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nice, hackable pure ruby & rack blog: [RubySlippers](http://ruby-slippers.heroku.com)

It used git to manage versioning of your posts and publishing as well. It is built to get a free blog going on heroku in record time!

~end shameless plug

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a platform called [Stipes](http://www.stipes.ch).

It's based on Sinatra and it is very light in terms of required resources.

I installed it on a Raspberry PI recently, for internal, single-user, usage and it works very well. I'm still working on it and any support is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not into installing a fully fledged blogging engine, [Bloggity](http://www.williambharding.com/blog/rails/bloggity-an-evolving-rails-blog-plugin/) may fit your needs, in fact you can use to add a blog to whatever app you may have.

Comment: @jrhicks: WordPress is much easier to deploy on shared hosting than a Rails based solution.